# Tensorflow: Keep 10% of the largest entries of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to filter a tensor by keeping 10% of the largest entries. Is there a Tensorflow function to do that? How would a possible implementation look like? I am looking for something that can handle tensors of shape `[N,W,H,C]` and `[N,W*H*C]`.

By filter I mean that the shape of the tensor remains the same but only the largest 10% are kept. Thus all entries become zero except the 10% largest.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of doing this would be computing the 90 percentile, for example with [`tf.contrib.distributions.percentile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/distributions/percentile):

```
import tensorflow as tf

images = ... # [N, W, H, C]
n = tf.shape(images)[0]
images_flat = tf.reshape(images, [n, -1])
p = tf.contrib.distributions.percentile(images_flat, 90, axis=1, interpolation='higher')
images_top10 = tf.where(images >= tf.reshape(p, [n, 1, 1, 1]),
                        images, tf.zeros_like(images))
```

If you want to be ready for TensorFlow 2.x, where [`tf.contrib` will be removed](https://github.com/tensorflow/community/blob/master/rfcs/20180907-contrib-sunset.md), you can instead use [TensorFlow Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/), which is where the [`percentile`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/percentile) function will be permanently in the future.

EDIT: If you want to do the filtering per channel, you can modify the code slightly like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

images = ... # [N, W, H, C]
shape = tf.shape(images)
n, c = shape[0], shape[3]
images_flat = tf.reshape(images, [n, -1, c])
p = tf.contrib.distributions.percentile(images_flat, 90, axis=1, interpolation='higher')
images_top10 = tf.where(images >= tf.reshape(p, [n, 1, 1, c]),
                        images, tf.zeros_like(images))
```

Comment: Can you explain how your code works? When I use `images = tf.random.uniform([1, 4, 4, 1])` it throws an error: `Cannot reshape a tensor with 16 elements to shape [1,1,1,1]`. What does `tf.contrib.distributions.percentile` compute? What does the `interpolation` parameter?

Comment: @Samuel There was an error, it should be `axis=1` instead of `axis=0`, it should work now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Samuel About how it works, the [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) `q` is literally a value such that `q%` of the given array elements are below it. Taking the 90 percentile and then masking out those values below it you would be left with only those in the top 10%.

Comment: Is it possible to apply the filter to every map `[W,H]` instead of the whole tensor?

Comment: @Samuel Right now the code computes one percentile per image and uses that percentile to filter the corresponding image (e.g. if you use `images = tf.random.uniform([5, 4, 4, 1])` you would get 5 different values in `p` and each of them would be used to filter each of the 5 images).

Comment: I would like to apply the filter to every channel separately, which right now is not possible. Is there an easy way to do that with your solution?

Comment: @Samuel Right I see what you mean. I have added a variation to filter per channel instead.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found any built-in method yet. Try this workaround:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def filter(tensor, ratio):
  num_entries = tf.reduce_prod(tensor.shape)
  num_to_keep = tf.cast(tf.multiply(ratio, tf.cast(num_entries, tf.float32)), tf.int32)
  # Calculate threshold
  x = tf.contrib.framework.sort(tf.reshape(tensor, [num_entries]))
  threshold = x[-num_to_keep]
  # Filter the tensor
  mask = tf.cast(tf.greater_equal(tensor, threshold), tf.float32)
  return tf.multiply(tensor, mask)

tensor = tf.constant(np.arange(40).reshape(2, 4, 5), dtype=tf.float32)
filtered_tensor = filter(tensor, 0.1)
# Print result
tf.InteractiveSession()
print(tensor.eval())
print(filtered_tensor.eval())
```